# access Jena TDB with OWLAPI

Tags: java, jena, owl, owl-api, triplestore

Is there a way to access to Jena TDB using OWL API, through Java API?

It seems that Jena doesn't support the OWL-API. 
As well as the RDF API, it has some  convenience functions (OntAPI) for accessing and updating the RDF when treated as an OWL ontology, though this doesn't support OWL 2.

Any Suggestions?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not currently. We (OWLAPI) are planning to add an adapter to allow using a TDB store, but this is still being thought through, not implemented.

Comment: What about Pellet API? In this post http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/jena-users/201311.mbox/%3CetPan.52961c0a.2eb141f2.3ac@maatarirooffice.mobile.usilu.net%3E  I've red this suggestion: "I saw some interesting code on the pellet website that show some interoperability between Jena and the OWL-API trough the Pellet API. I just don’t know how effective that can be"

Comment: I think I see what it's happening - you might be able to reason connected to a Jena model and answer through the OWLReasoner interface for OWLAPI. However I believe this might require a custom factory. I'm not aware of a simple way to do it, and for a large TDB ontology you'll probably run out of memory on the current OWLAPI implementation - the default is to load all axioms in memory.

Answer (score 0):

now there is [ONT-API](https://github.com/owlcs/ont-api) - a jena based OWLAPI-impl